# Compute Lightswitch Entity property based on date property in same record using Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I would like to add two computed properties to an entity in Lightswitch using VB.

1) One property would be computed and enter the month as Jan, Feb, Mar,... or January, February, March,... based on a date property entered in the same record. I assume  12 "If then else" statements would be the easiest but I am open to suggestions.

2) The second property is the "Year" and would compute and fill in the year (YYYY) based on the same date property.

I know this creates a redundancy in the record but it is going to be used with a group of existing reports. I am kind of new to VB.  Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is provided by Simon in the Visual Studio Forum:

[LightSWitch Forum Answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa0ce23f-17dc-40fc-a5f2-58b108274a1c/compute-lightswitch-entity-property-based-on-date-property-in-same-record-using-visual-basic?forum=lightswitch)

Private Sub MonthString_Compute(ByRef result As String)
    result = Format(Me.ThisDate, "MMMM") 
    'Change to "MMM" for month abbreviation
end Sub

Private Sub YearString_Compute(ByRef result As String)
    result = Format(Me.ThisDate, "yyyy").ToString
end Sub

The "yyyy" is case sensitive.